# Method to sequentially fill 2D vector<int> from specific index?

Tags: c++

What is the appropriate method in C++ to do the following:

Allow x to equal some larger `int` for this example.

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xx    xxxxxx0000xx
xx     xxxxx    xx
xx     xxxxx    xx
xx              xx
xx              xx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

This 2D `std::vector<int>` is what I currently have. I need to begin populating the blanks with increasing values beginning from the index of the `0` positons such that the follow occurs:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xx    xxxxxx0000xx
xx   99xxxxx1111xx
xx   98xxxxx2222xx
xx   98765433333xx
xx   98765444444xx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And continues until al blank spaces are filled. I have looked at `std::iota` but I am running on C++98 (imposed restriction). Reading up on `std::generate` and it seems like a good way to go, unsure about implementation.

Comment: Neither `iota` nor `generate` are good matches for this. You have to manually and explicitly loop over all lines and all columns to set the parts you want to set.

Comment: In your output you still have blanks, is this intentional?

Comment: Can you provide an actual  `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` as input and output? Give us some real code to work with.

Comment: This problem can trivially be solved with a breadth-first search algorithm, since this is an unweighted graph with bidirectional edges. populate a fifo queue with the starting zeroes and then for each element in the queue, assign a number to all surrounding, empty fields and add those to the end of the queue. repeat until queue is empty.

Comment: @AndyG Code at home. Me at work! However I will say that the output is originally a `std::vector<std::string>` of 2D that is looped over for each value `x` and then pushed to a `std::vector<int>` of 2D. In the actual code, there are no blanks because I cant skip the positions when populating a `std::vector<int>` (unless you know of a way?) so I fill those "blanks" with `-1`. So in my example above, in the actual code, every blank is a `-1` for the purpose of establishing the 2D `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: @flyx You're using words I've never heard of before...do you have an example of this?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I feel like loop is going to be huge. Loop once to fill `1` values, loop again to fill `2` values, etc. I would have to establish a condition that checks to see if any value for `[i][j]` equals `-1`("blank"). If not, find positions of next increment and adjacent cells.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you write the matrix in [row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) into an `std::vector<int>` named `m` and `width` is the number of digits in one row, this would be an implementation of a breadth-first search algorithm:

```
// these are the x values
#define OBSTACLE -1
// these are empty fields
#define EMPTY -2

std::vector<int> m;
int width;

// TODO: fill the vector here with OBSTACLEs and EMPTY and set the width!

// the list contains indexes of filled, yet unprocessed fields
std::queue<int> worklist;

// now initialize the starting zeroes. I am using the indexes
// from your example matrix here.
worklist.push(1 * width + 12); m[1 * width + 12] = 0; // second row, 13th field
worklist.push(1 * width + 13); m[1 * width + 13] = 0; // second row, 14th field
worklist.push(1 * width + 14); m[1 * width + 14] = 0; // .. and so on.
worklist.push(1 * width + 15); m[1 * width + 15] = 0;

// algorithm
while (worklist.size() > 0) {
    const int cur = worklist.front();
    worklist.pop();
    const int newval = m[cur] + 1;
    int directions[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    if (cur >= width) {
        // we are not on the first row, check upwards
        directions[0] = -width;
    }
    if (cur % width != 0) {
        // we are not on the first column, check left
        directions[1] = -1;
    }
    if ((cur + 1) % width != 0) {
        // we are not on the last column, check right
        directions[2] = 1;
    }
    if (cur + width < m.size()) {
        // we are not on the last row, check downwards
        directions[3] = width;
    }
    // I am not calculating diagonal connections here; you also seem to
    // want those. They would be trivial to add.
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        if (directions[i] != 0) {
            const int index = cur + directions[i];
            if (m[index] == EMPTY) {
                m[index] = newval;
                worklist.push(index);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: having complications with `const int cur = worklist.pop()`; Error: `a value type "void" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "const int"`

Comment: Also, you noted that diagonals are trivial, but I'm gonna go out on a limb here and ask that in order to make them, I am going to make "combinations" of the conditions for up, down, left and right..right? For example, if `[0]` = up, `[1]` = left, `[2]` = right, and `[3]` = down, then upper right is `[0][2]`?

Comment: Curious though how you are getting a 2D position from your single `vector<int>`. I'm only aware of a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` method.

Comment: Well you said you are using a *2D `std::vector<int>`*, so I assumed you transcoded the matrix into a single `std::vector<int>` instead of a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. The link to row-major order is how that is done, but the code can of course be changed to work with `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. I fixed the `pop()` mistake.

Comment: This is example code showing you how to implement the algorithm. You need to understand what it does instead of guessing (which you do judging by your direction question). As `direction` is an `int[]`, you can *not* access `direction[0][2]`. Try to rewrite the code for a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, the direction part will get easier.

Comment: While I do understand what it is doing, I don't always _see_ the best implementation method. You don't have to give the exact answer, but pointing me in the right direction generally solves it. Some things throw me off, like can I do `worklist.push(m[i][j])` where having in a prior loop determine that specific `[i][j]` was a `0`. The changing of `newval` is also a confusing bit as you set it to `m[cur] + 1` for a 1D vector, but `cur` is an `int` and `m` is a `std::vector<std::vector<int>` in my case so can `newval = m[cur][cur]` since `worklist.front()` would equal `0` initially?

Comment: Thanks for the `pop()` fix. Now to figure out how to turn your 1D code into 2D! I'm going to post an answer below to work on and then submit as final once working. Please feel free to edit/comment towards it.

Answer (score 0):

My attempt and turning @flyx code into a form that can support a `std::vector<std::vector<int>`. I'm struggling with the diagonal checks.

**I know the indentation is off, copied right from IDE.**

```
queue<pair<int, int> > worklist;

            for (size_t i = 0; i < nlevel.size(); i++) {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < nlevel[i].size(); j++) {
                    if (nlevel[i][j] == 0) {
                        /*cout << i << ' ' << j << endl;*/
                        worklist.push(make_pair(i,j));
                    }
                }
            }

            while (worklist.size() > 0) {
                pair<int, int> cur = worklist.front();
                worklist.pop();
                const int newval = nlevel[cur.first][cur.second] + 1;
                int directions[4] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
                int width = nlevel[0].size();
                int height = nlevel.size();
                if (cur.first > 0) {
                    // we are not on the first row, check upwards
                    directions[0] = -1;
                }
                if (cur.second > 0) {
                    // we are not on the first column, check left
                    directions[2] = -1;
                }
                if (cur.first < height) {
                    // we are not on the last row, check downwards
                    directions[1] = 1;
                }
                if (cur.second < width) {
                    // we are not on the last column, check right
                    directions[3] = 1;
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                    for (int j = 2; j < 4; j++) {
                        if (directions[i] != 0 && directions[j] != 0) {
                            const int xindex = cur.first + directions[j];
                            const int yindex = cur.second + directions[i];
                            //cout << xindex << ' ' << yindex << endl;
                            if (nlevel[xindex][yindex] == -1) {
                                nlevel[xindex][yindex] = newval;
                                worklist.push(make_pair(xindex, yindex));
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

            cout << endl;

            for (size_t i = 0; i < nlevel.size(); i++) {
                for (size_t j = 0; j < nlevel[i].size(); j++) {
                    cout << nlevel[i][j];
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
```

I believe I've gotten it mostly working however, without even spacing on the output its tough to follow! Never the less, here is the output:

```
xxxxXxxxxXxxxxXxxxxXxxxxXxxxxX
xxxxxx      xxxxx      xxx  xx
xxxxx        xxx       xx    x
xx     xx     x        x     x
X      xx              x  x  x
x      xx                 x  x
x      xxxxxxxxxxxxxx     x  x
x     xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  x
xFFFF x  xxxxxxxxxxxxxx      x
XFFFF x    xxxxxxxx          x
x     x      1               x
xxxxxxx      2        xxx    x
xxxxxx       3         x     x
x                            x
Xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2
-2-2-2-2-2-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-2-2-2-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-2-2-1-1-2-2
-2-2-2-2-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-2-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-2-1-1-1-1-2
-2-2-1-1-1-1-1-2-2-1-1-1-1-1-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-1-1-1-1-1-2
-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-1-1-2-1-1-2
-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-1-1-2
-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-1-1-1-1-1-2-1-1-2
-2-1-1-1-1-1-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-1-1-2
-20000-1-2-1-1-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-2
-20000-1-2-1-1-1-1-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2
-2-1-1-1-1-1-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2
-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-2-2-1-1-1-1-2
-2-2-2-2-2-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2-1-1-1-1-1-2
-2-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-2
-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2

-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2
-2-2-2-2-2-27779911-2-2-2-2-2171719192121-2-2-22727-2-2
-2-2-2-2-266688101012-2-2-216161818202022-2-226262628-2
-2-255555-2-299111113-21515171719192121-22525252727-2
-2444444-2-21010101212141416161818202022-22424-22628-2
-2333333-2-21111111113131515171719192121232325-22927-2
-2222222-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-22022222424-22830-2
-211111-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-23129-2
-200001-25050-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2343432323032-2
-200001-251494947-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-239373735353333313331-2
-211111-250504848464644444242404038383636343432343234-2
-2-2-2-2-2-2-2514949474745454343414139393737-2-2-235333533-2
-2-2-2-2-2-25250504848464644444242404038383838-23634363436-2
-2-1-1-1-1535151494947474545434341413939393939373537353735-2
-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2-2
```

There is a section in the lower left of the last grid that still has `-1` values and are not filling.

Comment: Use a `std::queue<std::pair<int, int>>` for this, you need the two indexes. `cur` will then be a `std::pair<int, int>` so to access its value, you'd do `m[cur.first][cur.second]`. That will allow you do to proper direction checks, e.g. `cur.first > 0` for checking whether you are in the first row. Also, stay with 4 directional values. For diagonals, it suffices to check e.g. *is there a left **and** a lower value* to check if there is a left-lower value.

Comment: @flyx How can you keep 4 directional values but check for 8? This is the only part hanging me up in the code. I understand the `if (a && b)...` logic, but its the assigning to `direction[i]` that doesn't make sense with me. Values of 1-4 are already assigned for up, down, left and right. So I need 4 more values do I not?

Comment: Change the order so that you have `[up, left, down, right]`. Then, inside the for-loop, check additionally for `if (directions[i] != 0 && directions[(i + 1) % 4] != 0)`. Target index will be `cur + directions[i] + directions[(i + 1) % 4]`. This gives you up-left for `i==0`, down-left for `i==1` and so on. (Suggestions based on my code, not yours, which doesn't work.)

Comment: @flyx Updated my script. I cant get the worklist populated, but I do not think I am implementing my checking correctly. I removed the use of `direction[i] = -width` or ``direction[i] = width` and replaced with `1` or `-1` because I either needed to move up or down one cell. However, I believe that using `+/-width` was going to the same place on the previous or next line by going forward or backwards `width` amount of positions.

Comment: Now you are moving *only* diagonally, which explains the errors. The `direction` code is not really helpful for `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, but since you have it, add two loops before the current nested loops that only loop through the horizontal / vertical directions and fill those fields.

Comment: @flyx So just add two `for` loops before the one currently beginning with `i=0;i<2;i++`? One will just change the `xindex` value while the other changes the `yindex` and the code I have currently checks all the 4 corners. I was wondering when I did a `cout` of the new indices (I commented out the new `make_pair`) that I was getting only 32 values returned, when I should've been getting 62 (8 cells per initial cell). Ill keep you updated.